# How to restructure Promoted links with multiple lines in "Sharepoint Online"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, promoted-links

How to restructure a Promoted links list with multiple lines in **Sharepoint Online**?

I tried inserting this CSS:

```
<style>
.ms-promlink-body{
width:550px;
}
</style>
```

But still it is not working.

When I tried searching for blogs, I'm am not finding how to do it for **Sharepoint Online**.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint Online is not different from SharePoint 2013 in this regard. Try the following :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ms-promlink-root > .ms-promlink-header { display: none; }
    .ms-promlink-root .ms-promlink-body { width: auto; height: auto; }
</style>
```

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. @Deivanarayanan could you mark my answer as accepted ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For promotion link try this css

```
<style>.ms-tileview-tile-root{width:100%}</style>
```

Hope this will work.